# Plot from Matplotlib and Pandas on the same figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need two plots on the same figure. One of them is described by a Dataframe and the other by numpy arrays. Is there a way to plot them on the same figure without converting any of them ?

I know how to make multiple plots if all are numpy arrays or if all are Dataframes, but I don't know what to do when they have mixed types. For example, the following does not work:

```
ax=plt.plot(xv,yv)
df.plot.scatter(x='Column1',y='Column2',ax=ax)
```

Comment: Can you share your data? What is `xv`, 'yv' and `df`? It makes life much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two plots on the same figure:

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(xv,yv)
df.plot.scatter(x='Column1',y='Column2',ax=ax2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well. I want them on the same plot, not on two separate subplots.

Comment: I tried using ax1 for both plots, it works but I end up with an empty and useless subplot.

Comment: Actually the same with plt.subplots(1) gets the job done. Thanks !

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the result you were trying to get. You asked for two plots on the same figure, which in matplotlib language means two axes usually. In your case, it sounds like you want two plots on one axis.